# How do I change from Python 3 to Python 2 in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have both Python 3 (*C:\Python\Python38\python.exe*) and Python 2 (*C:\Python\Python27\python.exe*) installed on my Windows 10 computer, and I want to use Python 2 for a project in VSCode.

However, when I select my interpreter to Python 2.7.1 32--bit and run my code, it still runs in Python 3. Typing `python -V` in PowerShell or Python window gives me "Python 3.8.2". Both versions have been added to my PATH variables, so I am not quite sure why selecting Python 2 in the VSCode interpreter menu still gives me Python 3.

Has anyone encountered anything similar?

Comment: Maybe this answer helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/66102653/1202124 (essentially one way to make this work is to put the v2.7.1 path before the v3 one in your environment variable. Only problem with this is that this will change the setting globally in your os, so any CLI you use will have 2.7.1. as default)

Comment: have you looked at the lower left of the statusbar

Comment: Yeah, strangely, the bottom status bar says "Python 2.7.1". Perhaps there is a way to change the default version that the powershell uses? Or is there a way to at least force VSCode to use Python 2 that I can type in the console and run manually?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add `print(sys.prefix)` to check which python interpreter you are using? The `python --version` you get in the VSCode is not the python interpreter you are using. Python2 works well in my VSCode.

And if you want to distinguish the python2 and python3 clearly. You can rename the `python.exe` to `python2.exe` which under the Python2 installation Folder. Then in the Powershell, you can get `python3` through the `python` command and `python2` through the `python2` command.